# Is It Possible To Render Only Those Layers Inside Of Viewport?

Tags: openlayers

Since I have some "heavy" layers on the OpenLayers map it takes quite some time to load it. I am unsing TileWMS Source. When I zoom in to the specific area, everytime I have to wait for all layers to be loaded before I can normally interact with  the map. Is there a way that ol only rerenders layers in the visible area of the map, aka that it doesnt enter prerender and postrender if its not in the view?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in layers called `strategy`. It's about how OpenLayers request for data from GeoServer. Default `strategy` is `module:ol/loadingstrategy~all` that requests for the whole layer.
But there is also another option for loading strategy called `module:ol/loadingstrategy.bbox`. By setting this value for strategy in the layer you can request for the current extent of the map. see [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html?q=bbox) for OpenLayers example.

After setting bbox option to your layer you should change the loading function or layer URL. For example mention above you should set a function for source URL that loads only the current extent.

```
var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent) {
    return 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
        'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
        'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'; // giving current extent to load data
  },
  strategy: bboxStrategy // telling openlayers to not load all data!
});
```

Comment: Do you know if something similar exists for TileWMS?

Comment: @jssql tileWMS has this option too. Check the params option [here](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS-TileWMS.html).

Comment: If you are reffering to bbox inside of params, it is written that it is set dynamically. Didnt find option that acts like strategy in vector layer.

Comment: In tileWMS layers data load as tiles. so it doesn't load whole data. As you mentioned bbox set dynamically, this means OpenLayers and GeoServer automatically handle efficient tile loading. if you have a problem/low speed in loading there might be another problem somewhere else. I'm not sure but some caching or interaction might cause this.